# Unable to click on submenu using Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to click on a submenu in a webpage. Submenu will be displayed when I just hover over the main menu. I have referred many solutions and it sill doesn't work.
And there are no iframes on the page.

Below is the code:

```
    Actions ac = new Actions(d);
    WebElement we = d.findElement(By.xpath("(//ul[@id='menu-top-menu']//li)[1]"));
    ac.moveToElement(we).perform();
    
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(d, 10);
    WebElement we2 = wait.until(
            ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("(//ul[@id='menu-top-menu']//li//ul//li[2]//a)[1]")));
    ac.moveToElement(we2).click().perform();
```

Can someone please help me out with it?.

Comment: Have you tried with this xpath `//ul[@id='menu-top-menu']`, at first part with hover?

Comment: Mate, I've just noticed that the same script works fine in Chrome. But in Firefox, I'm facing the issue. And this is the right xpath (//ul[@id='menu-top-menu']//li)[1]

Comment: Can you show us the DOM or provide us some sample to test with it?

Comment: Would you prefer the URL that I'm using?.https://psarips.one/ is the website and the action that I'm trying to do is, hover over Movies and click on Action. Like I said the issue is only with Firefox.

Comment: Do you really need to simulate `mousein` and `click` or you need just the link of a specific `a` from list?

Comment: If you say your code works with `chromedriver` but with `geckodriver` not. Maybe `Actions` class not works with `geckodriver`. I remember I read while ago(years) about an issue like that.

Comment: Only after hovering over I'll be able to see that link.

Comment: You can get that link from DOM. If it's not necessary to simulate `mousein` and `click`.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not necessary to simulate `mousein` and `click`, you can get the `href` value of `a` element and direct access with `driver`.

You just need to check if element is present.

```
String xpathAction = "//ul[@id='menu-top-menu'] /li[1] /ul /li /a[text() = 'Action']";

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
String hrefAction = wait.until(
                        ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xpathAction))
                    ).getAttribute("href");

driver.get(hrefAction);
```